# linq NullReferenceException while checking for null reference

Tags: c#, linq-to-objects

I have the following LINQ query:

```
List<FileInputItem> inputList = GetInputList();
var results = from FileInputItem f in inputList
              where ( Path.GetDirectoryName(f.Folder).ToLower().Trim() == somePath
                     || Path.GetDirectoryName(f.Folder).ToLower().Trim() == someOtherPath ) 
                    && f.Expression == null
             select f;
```

Every time this query is executed, it generates a NullReferenceException.  If I remove the condition  `f.Expression == null` or change it to `f.Expression != null`, the query executes normally (giving the wrong results, of course).

The relevant bits of `FileInputItem` look like this:

```
[Serializable]
public class FileInputItem
{
    [XmlElement("Folder")]
    public string Folder { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Expression")]
    public string Expression { get; set; }

    /*SNIP.  Irrelevant properties */
}
```

I'm new to LINQ to objects, so I'm probably missing something fundamental here.  What's the deal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are probably cases where FileInputItem.Folder is null (which would cause an exception with "Path.GetDirectoryName(f.Folder).ToLower().Trim()"), and those cases happen to coincide with the cases where FileInputItem.Expression is null.

Try adding "f.Folder != null" to the beginning of your where clause and see if that fixes the issue.  If so, determine how you want to handle those cases when Folder is null.

Comment: Doesn't the first part of the && is evaluated first?

Comment: Exactly right. I had naively assumed that Folder would never be null.

Comment: Thanks @brickner, that is correct.  I've updated the post to state it should be at the beginning

Comment: What I've actually tried to say is how come f be null if Path.GetDirectoryName(f.Folder).ToLower().Trim() is evaluated first?

Answer (score 0):

You could also try String.IsNullOrEmpty(f.Expression)

Comment: That's actually what I was using initially.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

```
List<FileInputItem> inputList = GetInputList();
var results = from FileInputItem f in inputList
              where f.Folder != null && f.Expression == null
              let path = Path.GetDirectoryName(f.Folder).ToLower().Trim()
              where path == somePath || path = someOtherpath
              select f;
```